# Bridged Network in VirtualBox

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have just installed Oracle VMBox version 4.2.6 & Ubuntu 12.04.

Am trying to use Bridge network connection but for some reasons it is giving me error as:

```
Invalid settings detected
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Unfortunately even after a host reboot I cant see any adapter name in the dropdown for *"Name"*. Are there any settings need to be done for that as well?

**EDIT**

when I tried executing this command :

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Result :

```
 sudo: /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: command not found
```

Comment: If the command /etc/init.d/vboxdrv doesn't exist, try to reinstall virtualbox.

Comment: Did you already try a reinstallation?

Comment: @EricCarvalho : Nope any suggestions?

Comment: Just to make things clear: you're using VirtualBox to run a Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine on a Windows host, right?

Comment: So this problem is not related to Ubuntu, it's about VirtualBox running on Windows. I can only suggest you to remove and reinstall VirtualBox. Maybe there's some problem with the current installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that on several occasions, every time it was some failed module.

On a command line type `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` and watch the output for error messages. If there are no errors that *should* get you going, if there are any please post them into your question.